# Model of $ZFC$ where the internal powerset is the external powerset

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

> Is there a name for models $M$ of $ZFC$ where the internal powerset is the external powerset?

If so, is the assumption of a transitive model where the internal powerset is the external powerset a stronger/weaker assumption than just assuming a transitive model, or is it just different?

Comment: What would it mean for the internal and external power sets to be the same if $M$ is not an inner model?

Comment: @MarkSaving For all I know this requirement may force a model to have all the ordinals; transitivity already gives that we have the same finite ordinals, and we can construct the finite stages of the cumulative hierarchy internally if we have transitivity and an internal powerset matching the external one. It might be possible to show that these requirements together force the model to be inner.

Comment: $V_\kappa$? But more seriously, supertransitive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertransitive_class

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can prove by induction, that if $M$ is a model of $\sf ZF$ which computes power sets correctly, then $M$ is an initial segment of the universe, that is $M=V$ or for some $\alpha$, $M=V_\alpha$.

To see this, note that the empty set must be in $M$, and it must be the correct empty set, since if $x\in M$ is any set, $\mathcal P(x)$ is computed correctly, so it must be that $\varnothing^M=\varnothing$. Now, by recursion show that if $\alpha\in M$ is an ordinal, $V_\alpha\in M$.

So, the consistency strength of this sort of *set* model is a worldly cardinal which is quite a bit stronger than the existence of a transitive model.

(The term [supertransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertransitive_class) applies here, but it's not common enough that everyone will immediately know what it means.)